# Angular 5: Updating template in Observable chain not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, observable

If I have a component and want to show a loader

component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .do(x => this.contentLoading = true)
      .switchMap(x => this.getClientSearchResults())
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.clientSearchResults = x;
        this.contentLoading = false
      });
  }
```

template

```
<mat-progress-spinner *ngIf="contentLoading" color="accent" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
```

The loader will show the first time the page loads, but then any change to the params will no longer show the loader. I can see the Observable chain is running each time with a `console.log`. Does `ngZone` not detect it whilst it is still running the Observable chain?

Answer (score 0):

The `switchMap` will *complete* the previous observable, and switch to the new observable. This means that after the first parameter change is emitted that the `subscribe` will no longer receive future changes.

I think what you wanted to use was `mergeMap` instead.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Comment: Even when I change it to `mergeMap`, it still does not show my loader the second time searching, despite running the code `this.contentLoading = true`